# Can you validate type property names against a union type?

Tags: typescript, union-types

Given

```
type UnionType = 'prop1' | 'prop2' | 'prop3';

type DerivedType = {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: number;
  prop3: boolean;
};
```

Is there a way to declare `DerivedType` so that if I add a member to `UnionType` without adding the corresponding property to `DerivedType` I'll get a TypeScript error?

If the types of the properties were all the same this would be trivial, but they aren't.

I don't want `Record<UnionType, any>` - I want specific types for each property.

The actual use case involves a union type that is `keyof` a *different* type; the "derived" type specifies configurations for each of the properties. The goal is to keep all of these types in sync.

Comment: And why not just define `type UnionType = keyof DerivedType`? (if there's a reason why you can't, please [edit] it into the question).  I mean, you could do something like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Wy2M2w), but `keyof DerivedType` is so simple comparatively that I'd hope there's a good reason why you can't do that.  How should we proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz I added a paragraph covering this. Your linked example seems to work; care to post that as an answer?

Comment: Okay, your explanation makes sense. I'll post an answer when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you can't or don't want to refactor so that `UnionType` is defined in terms of `DerivedType` or so that both `UnionType` and `DerivedType` are defined in terms of something else, you can write your own `CheckKeys<K, T>` utility type which will evaluate to `T`, but issue a compiler error unless the keys of `T` are seen to be exactly `K` with nothing missing or extra (although there might be edge cases).

Here's one way to do it:

```
type CheckKeys<
  K extends PropertyKey,
  T extends Record<K, any> & Record<Exclude<keyof T, K>, never>
> = T;
```

Here `T` is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) so that it definitely has all of `K` as keys (since it extends `Record<K, any>` using [the `Record` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type)), and also (via [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)) any keys of `T` that are *not* in `K` (using [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion)) must have properties of [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type). Since only `never` is assignable to `never` and you're not likely to set property types to `never` to begin with, this should more or less enforce the restriction you're looking for.  Let's test it:

```
type UnionType = 'prop1' | 'prop2' | 'prop3';

type DerivedType = CheckKeys<UnionType,
  { prop1: string; prop2: number; prop3: boolean; }
>; // okay

type ExtraKey = CheckKeys<UnionType,
  { prop1: string, prop2: number, prop3: boolean, prop4: Date } // error!
// Types of property 'prop4' are incompatible.
>

type MissingKey = CheckKeys<UnionType,
  { prop1: string, prop2: number } // error!
// Property 'prop3' is missing.
>
```

Looks good. `DerivedType` is still the same type as before, and it compiles without error.  But if you add or remove a key, you get the requisite compiler error mentioning where the problem is.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAwgCygYwNYGkpgM4B5gwzoxQAeIUAdgCbYwAKATgPbSPiZgA0BMAKiXJVaMAEopmjarnRcYAQ0pgAfDABkYiVNwBRUsgA2AV2pRcqLMwBm-OemVzKUAG5RGy4KoC8-ANzBQSFgAVUoAS2ZKPiCYHwByCBYIAEY4mAAfGASkgCY0zOzWAGY4-0DoGAARNzDXamiKn0QUDCw8UIiooJ5CAG8YRNZkgC4YbBBGMMoAc18B3NHKIwBbACM3OcGIItHV5mYDKEU5gF9POYB6C5hmVHkwAPAKvQn5Tlj4JDROdvDIhqgPRg-S2IzGEym0zkWxyixW60Y0KSOxgewOR0oSNYABZRpV5BQYCcYFcSIwWIwAITAUkAujWeasNzgLJbbFpeSMWBTZDMZYQAlhVaHAB0nkeMQAsmFsNhIe8ml9WjhcB1-t1eCCkmDxpMZliILCYEs1m4iSTrm4KdTSUwmewwKzkWkZTBljK5TMxR5gEA)

Comment: I tested this and it works perfectly. I replaced the `any` with `unknown` and it still works. Thank you!